# How to make child array pagination with node js and aws dynamo db

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to make pagination of "**car_types**" using aws dynamo db and node js. I don't want to use js, Can we make it using dynamo db ? I want total items, total page, page size, current page and data in response.

```
{
  "uid": "222-3333",
  "car_types": [
    {
      "description": "fsdf",
      "title": "sdfsd"
    },
    {
      "description": "fdfdfdf",
      "title": "dfdfd"
    },
    {
      "description": "dasda",
      "title": "asdas"
    },
    {
      "description": "dasd",
      "title": "asdas"
    },
    {
      "description": "dasdasd",
      "title": "asdas"
    }
  ]
}
```

Aws Dynamo DB and Node js Code, Which I used to get result.

```
export function get_car_types_list(){

  var params = {
    TableName : "cms_cars",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#uid = :uid",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#uid": "uid"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":uid": "222-3333"
    }
};

return docClient.query(params).promise()
.then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;

}).catch( (err) => {
  console.log('got Error', err);
  });


}
```

I want Result using dynamo db query:

```
{
"totalItem":5,
"totalPage":1,
"pageSize":"1",
"currentPage":"1",
  "car_types": [
    {
      "description": "fsdf",
      "title": "sdfsd"
    },
    {
      "description": "fdfdfdf",
      "title": "dfdfd"
    },
    {
      "description": "dasda",
      "title": "asdas"
    },
    {
      "description": "dasd",
      "title": "asdas"
    },
    {
      "description": "dasdasd",
      "title": "asdas"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

DynamoDb will return 1 mb data when `scan/query` is executed, also `LastEvaluatedKey` is added to result if there are any remaining data. If you pass `ExclusiveStartKey: LastEvaluatedKey` you can `scan/query` with pagination. I added some tweaks to your approach, it may help you.

Edit: You can limit the result by passing `Limit: Number` to your params. This will allow you to limit the returning item count and you can get more with `LastEvaluatedKey`.

```
export function get_car_types_list(LastEvaluatedKey){

  var params = {
    TableName : "cms_cars",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#uid = :uid",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#uid": "uid"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":uid": "222-3333"
    },
    Limit: 5,
};
if (LastEvaluatedKey) {
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = LastEvaluatedKey;
}
return docClient.query(params).promise()
.then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return data;

}).catch( (err) => {
  console.log('got Error', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I want to apply pagination on specific data that is "car_types", don't want to apply on whole result.

Comment: @TahaFarooqui Oh I see but that is not possible with DynamoDb. It doesn' t provide such functionality at all.